# How do you set the background image of a plain UIBarButtonItem?

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem, uibarbuttonitemstyle

If my UIBarButtonItem (`lightButton`) has a style of Bordered, either of the following lines change the background image:

```
[lightButton setBackgroundImage:resizeableImage forState:UIControlStateNormal style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[lightButton setBackgroundImage:resizeableImage forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

If the button has a style of Plain, then neither of the following lines change the background image:

```
[lightButton setBackgroundImage:resizeableImage forState:UIControlStateNormal style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[lightButton setBackgroundImage:resizeableImage forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Is it possible to change the background image of a Plain UIBarButtonItem, other than using `initWithCustomView:`?

Answer (score 2):

you can use it.

```
UIButton *modalViewButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
UIImage* imagex = [UIImage imageNamed:@"xxxx.png"];
[modalViewButton addTarget:self action:sel forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[modalViewButton setImage:btnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
//modalViewButton setBackImage......
[modalViewButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, imagex.size.width, imagex.size.height)];
UIBarButtonItem *modalBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:modalViewButton];
```